# Regex redirect to remove dynamic string at the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

i need to remove the dynamic autogenerated string from the end of the URL.

this string is generated by searching products in the site and if copied or if page is refreshed the url gives 404 error.

url example:
`https://www.ringomusic.net/prodotto/dw-blocchetto-lug-design-series-per-tom-rullante-cromato/&amp;_rt_nonce=96ff51275b`

final url:
`https://www.ringomusic.net/prodotto/dw-blocchetto-lug-design-series-per-tom-rullante-cromato/`

we use [redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) that supports regex redirect.

anyone can help with a regex? thanks!

Comment: You should rather try and identify the cause of the _actual_ problem - which here appears to be the generation of a _faulty_ URL to begin with. The `&amp;` should not be HTML-encoded, and it should not be an `&`, but a `?` to begin with here. Whatever added this `_rt_nonce` parameter to the URL, did mess up.

Comment: the string is generated by relevanssi plugin. when the search result is only one it redirect to the result instead of the search results page. i tried to search online but i did not found any resource.

Comment: solved with this function:

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'one_match_redirect' );
function one_match_redirect() {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        if ( 1 === $wp_query->post_count ) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $wp_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}